# Maximum likelihood estimator of a product of non-negative functions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $a(\cdot)$ and $b(\cdot)$ are two non-negative functions such that 
$$f(x;\theta)=a(\theta)b(x)$$
is a probability density function for each $\theta > 0$. Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

My try: Our likelihood function is given by
$$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n a(\theta)b(x_i) = a(\theta)^nb(x)^n$$
The log likelihood function is given by
$$\ln L(\theta) = n\ln a(\theta) + n \ln b(x)$$
Equating it to zero we get
$$\ln a (\theta) = - \ln b(x)$$
which obviously leads to nowhere.

Moreover, the question itself seems weird to me. I am used to the form of "Given a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ of size $n$ (...)", since this is missing now, does this imply that I cannot use the usual method I demonstrated above?

Lastly, if you want to, could you check the exercise below for errors?

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ denote a random sample from
$$f(x;\theta) = f_\theta (x) = \theta f_1(x) + (1-\theta)f_0 (x)$$
where $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ and $f_0(\cdot)$ and $f_1(\cdot)$ are known densities, estimate $\theta$ by the method of moments.

Answer: First, we need to write $E[X]$ in a better form:
\begin{align*}
E[x] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot f(x;\theta)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\theta f_1(x) + (1-\theta)f_0 (x))dx \\
&= \theta \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot f_1 (x)dx + (1-\theta)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot f_0 (x)dx \\
&= \theta \int x(f_1-f_0)dx + \int x f_0 dx \\
&=\theta \left(E_1\left[x\right] - E_0\left[x\right]\right) + E_0\left[x\right]
\end{align*}
Equating this to the first sample moment ($m_1'$) we get:
\begin{align*}
m_1'= \theta \left(E_1\left[x\right] - E_0\left[x\right]\right) + E_0\left[x\right]
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to 
\begin{align*}
\theta = \dfrac{m_1' - E_0[x]}{E_1[x] - E_0[x]}
\end{align*}
Hence, our method of moments estimator for $\theta$ is given by:
$$\hat{\theta} = \dfrac{m_1' - E_0[x]}{E_1[x] - E_0[x]}$$

Both are questions from "Introduction to the theory of statistics" by Mood, Graybill and Boes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^n b(x_i)=b(x)^n$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StefanHansen When looking back, you're obviously right. What would you suggest how I should continue?

Comment: Continue by keeping $\prod_{i=1}^n b(x_i)$ as it is. Moreover, you want to solve $l'(\theta)=0$, not $l(\theta)=0$, where $l$ is the log-likelihood.

Comment: @StefanHansen Yes, I also spotted that mistake. It has been some time since I had to do this. Continuing on your advice: $\ln L(\theta) = n \ln a (\theta) + \sum_i \ln b(x_i)$. Differentiate wrt to $\theta$ and set equal to zero to get: $\dfrac{n\cdot a'(\theta)}{a(\theta)} = 0$ since $\sum_i \ln b(x_i)$ is just a constant. Which gives $a'(\theta)=0$. Do you think this is the answer?

Comment: This assumes that $a$ is differentiable. Are you sure that you haven't incorrectly stated the problem? Exercise 39 in the book you mention has $f(x;\theta)=a(\theta)b(x)I_{(0,\theta)}(x)$.

Comment: That is the exercise, could you work it out please?

Comment: Not sure how to solve it without additional assumptions on $a$, sorry.

Comment: What additional assumptions do you need? Just differentiability or more (restrictive) assumptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another example where including the (crucial) indicator functions in the densities simplifies everything... Here the PDF is
$$
f(x;\theta)=a(\theta)b(x)\mathbf 1_{[0,\theta]}(x),
$$
where 
$$
\frac1{a(\theta)}=\int_0^\theta b(x)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
hence the likelihood of a sample $\mathbf x=(x_k)$ is
$$
L(\mathbf x,\theta)=\prod_kf(x_k;\theta)=a(\theta)^n\,\mathbf 1_{\theta\geqslant m(\mathbf x)}\,\prod_kb(x_k),
$$
where
$$
m(\mathbf x)=\max_kx_k.
$$
The last product does not depend on $\theta$ hence one can forget it. The indicator function shows that $L(\mathbf x,\theta)$ can be nonzero only when $\theta\geqslant m(\mathbf x)$. And $\theta\mapsto a(\theta)$ is nonincreasing hence one looks for $\theta$ as small as possible. Finally, $L(\mathbf x,\theta)$ is maximal when $\theta=\hat\theta(\mathbf x)$ with
$$
\hat\theta(\mathbf x)=m(\mathbf x).
$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got the $1/a(\theta) = \int_0^\theta b(x) dx$ equality? Or (I think equivalently), why including the indicator function is necessary

Comment: Because for every $\theta$, the function $f(\ ;\theta)$ must integrate to $1$ and $$\int_\mathbb Rf(x;\theta)\mathrm dx=a(\theta)\int_0^\theta b(x)\mathrm dx.$$